# Model fitting to data by using machine learning algorithms?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, fitting

I am trying to fit an equation to data. I know the form of the equation but I need to know constants parameters in the equation. I used non-linear fitting and optimization techniques but I could not get promising results.

This can be a dump question but I wonder if it is possible to fit an equation to data by using machine learning algorithms such as guassion process, neural network and so.

For example, I have data and I wanna fit this equation: a*sin(x) +b*cos(x). Is it possible to find the constants of "a" and "b"?

Comment: @nickflees answer is right on. For future reference, you would only want to use something like a Gaussian process or neural network if you don't know the the functional form, i.e, you have a bunch of $(x_i, f(x_i))$ pairs but don't know anything (helpful) about $f$.

Comment: That is what I was asking actually. I tried bunch of regression techniques but I could not get the satisfying results. Therefore I was wondering if I could make use of machine learning algorithms for fitting a functional form (e.g. a*sin(x)+b*cos(c)) to a data. But you are saying it is not possible right? Btw thank you and @nickflees for response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, and as long as I'm not making an incorrect assumption, you could accomplish this using multivariable linear regression with transformations on the independent variables.

Your $X$ variables would be:
$X_{1}=\sin(x)$
and
$X_{2}=\cos(x)$

and then you can find the coefficients $b_{1}$ and $b_{2}$ by fitting the equation
$$Y=b_{1}X_{1} + b_{2}X_{2}$$